# How to change Bullet Color of Lists with React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I want to display random bullet color of UsersList. How can I do it? Below is my code:

```
const UsersList = props => (
  <div className={styles.Users}>
    <div className={styles.UsersOnline}>
      {props.users.length} people online
    </div>
    <ul className={styles.UsersList}>
      {
        props.users.map((user) => {
          return (
            <li key={user.id} className={styles.UserItem}>
              {user.name}
            </li>
          );
        })
      }
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for only CSS, which is the following:

```
ul {
   list-style: none;
}

ul li::before {
   content: "\2022";
   color: "red";
}
```

By default, it is not possible to change the bullet color of a list item. So you first you have to hide the bullets, then add *content: "\2022";* for a bullet (unicode) and change the color.